# How to create a setup script to make python script workable in Ubuntu environment?

Tags: python, ubuntu, environment-variables, executable, environment

I am a newbie in Python. I've done some python script, I write in windows environment. I would like to make that script workable on Ubuntu, without doing package installation again as I did in windows environment. My expectation when I copy the script to Ubuntu environment, it will running directly. Is it possible?

So far, I write a setup.py to check the installation, but when I run it on Ubuntu environment, it need to install some `pip` package again.

```
import subprocess

req = {
    "pip", "pyunpack", "patool", "Archive"
}


def existing_package():
    result = subprocess.run(["pip", "list"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = result.stdout.decode('utf-8').split("\n")
    return [r.split()[0] for r in result[2:-1]]


def main():
    exist = set(existing_package())
    if req.issubset(exist):
        print(f"✓ All package has installed successfully\n")
    else:
        print(f"This package {req - exist} is not installed")
        input("Press Enter to install...")
        for request in req - exist:
            subprocess.run(["pip", "install", request])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Anyone can give me idea please.  Thank you so much

Comment: what exactly is your question here?

Comment: I need an advice how to make my script workable in Ubuntu environment without doing package installation anymore

Comment: You cant use a package you havent installed. So either you modify your script to not rely on those packages or you have to install them.

Comment: The usual solution is to (1) declare your dependencies in a standard place (traditionally `setup.py`; more recently, `setup.cfg` or `pyproject.toml`; and (2) use a virtual environment to pull in the dependencies if you don't want to install them system-wide. This is almost certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to ensure a script has all of its required packages installed. The simplest way is to use pip, here's an example

```sh
# While developing
pip install pyunpack patool Archive
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

```sh
# On your (ubuntu) server
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

While this will most likely work it's not recommended, mostly because you might update packages that are used by Ubuntu itself.
Here's a list of ways to achieve this more elegantly, sorted by complexity.

- [virtual envs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)
- [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)
- [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/)
- [https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/](http://docker)

(This list is nowhere near complete, just some of the tools I've enjoyed using in the past.)